# MSBuild - working except not deploying web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, webdeploy, azure-devops

Visual Studio 2012 Express (Update 2), deploying MVC 4 app all through Team Foundation Service with GIT - then using a build to deploy to a Windows 2008 Server (using MSBuild Arguments).

All works - except web.config not being deployed (it is going into the git repository on TFService).

When deploying directly from VS - you have to right click web.config and choose 'copy always' for web.config to go up. Is there an equivalent option - or an MSBuild Argument I can use - to ensure web.config is deployed?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you copy the relevant section pertaining to the web.config from your project file?

Comment: Are you talking about this? '<Content Include="Web.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>'